# How can i get menu title from given id in Joomla

Tags: joomla, menu

I don't know if this is silly question, sorry about that. But i am newbie in joomla, and i have a problem to get menu title from given id.

```
is that possible ? if yes, how can i do it ?
```

Comment: What version of Joomla?

Comment: @Lodder version 1.5x..

Comment: You will need to make use of `JSite::getMenu`. Not sure on the exact code as I do not use such an old version of Joomla, nor should you. I'm sure you can find the answer with some research

Answer (score 1):

```
/** Getting the Menu ID of Menu was clicked by user **/
$menu    =   &JSite::getMenu();
$id    =   $menu->getActive()->id;

/** Getting the Title of the Menu by using id. **/
$db    = JFactory::getDBO();
$query    = "SELECT title FROM kjs_menu WHERE id = $id";
$db->setQuery($query);
$rows    = $db->loadObjectList();
$itemrow = $rows[0];
$title   =   $itemrow->title;

echo "Menu you have clicked is : ".$title;
```

//or this is short method which can guide you:

```
$active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
echo $active->title;
```

getActive gives back an object if it is able to get an active menu, so the object also include the title.
To make sure you have an object check it before you do any output.